# Every Hilbert space is connected

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, connectedness

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Proving $H$ is connected, suppose $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a orthogonal basis of $H$. Thus $H=\bigoplus_{i\in I} \Bbb C e_i$. Clearly  $\Bbb Ce_i$  is connected for every $i$, which leads us to connection of $H$.

Is my process correct? Please let me to know your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how $H=\bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb C e_i$ becomes a topological statement, so what is your reasoning here? I'd suggest an alternative: Use straight line paths to show path-connectedness.

Comment: @Christoph : $H$ is a vector space so it's evident to write $H = \bigoplus \Bbb Ce_i$

Comment: Still this is a statement about direct sums of vector spaces, no topology involved. How do you use this to talk about connectivity, a topological feature?

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks so much